# How to generate a HTML API documentation in VS 2005 and 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I have done my project and now it is documentation time. Up to now I was able to generate the XML files from the project. Now I want to get the HTML API out of it. But I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Sandcastle: see [here](http://www.codeplex.com/Sandcastle) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/sandcastle/). There are various tools available to make the building easier, such as [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://www.codeplex.com/SHFB).

Comment: thanx... i'm downloading it now.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can generate MSDN style documentation with [Sandcastle.](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=E82EA71D-DA89-42EE-A715-696E3A4873B2&displaylang=en)

Comment: thanx i'm downloading it now.. :)

Answer (score 1):

This takes a little bit of figuring out, but I recommend using Sandcastle. If you're familiar with nDoc it is very similar.

[Sandcastle Download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=E82EA71D-DA89-42EE-A715-696E3A4873B2&displaylang=en)

Comment: thanx i'm downloading it now.. :)